# QGIS 3.16 Visibility Analysis "Error! No Viewpoints in the chosen area!"

Tags: qgis-plugins, viewshed, visibility

I've got a problem with the Visibility Analysis Plugin. It creates Viewpoints without a problem. But if I want to use the temporary output file it says this:
[image]

Even when I save the file in different formats, the same message appears. Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Comment: Can you add edit you question and the error message as text?